# Find the locus of the point

Tags: geometry

Let P be a variable point on a given line and let A be any given fixed point. Find the locus of the point Q lying on AP or AP produced such that AP/AQ= constant.I think if A doesn't lie on the given line
then the locus of the line will be any line parallel to the given line . In order to  show this, let us assume that P and P' be any two points on the given line and let Q and Q' be two points on AP and AP'
such that AQ/AP=AQ'/AP' in triangle APP'.Consequently,QQ' will be parallel to the given line .Conversely,
one can show that for QQ' being any line parallel to the given line, AQ/AP=AQ'/AP'.However,if A lies on the given line what should be the locus of Q?Please help me verify this.

Answer (score 1):

The locus will the given line itself since every point on this line can be regarded as some $Q$ for a given constant.